# Xamarin Forms Navigation Page bar with only text (no icon)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I disable the xamarin icon in the navigation page bar and set the title?

Answer (score 1):

We can access the ActionBar Icon and set it to transparent in the Android Project, Code:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
    LoadApplication (new App ());
    this.ActionBar.SetIcon ((int)Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));
}
```

Page has a title property that can be set. You can do it in the constructor something like this:

```
 this.Title = "my page";
```

Comment: Title must be visible in the actionbar ? and I'm using Xamarin Forms pages

Comment: Yes it will be visible in action bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to remove the icon.

```
ActionBar.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
```

And to set the title you can use the code in C#

```
this.Title="mypage"
```

or for Xaml put the below attribute in the ContentPage node

```
Title="mypage"
```

Comment: `ActionBar.SetIcon` is not static